# Full header in scrbook

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, double-sided, scrpage2

I want to produce a full header including margins. The even page header is correct. But the odd page header does not include the margin in the left side.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt
%,bindingoffset=30pt
,asymmetric
,reversemarginpar
,showframe]{geometry}


\usepackage[ilines, headsepline]{scrpage2}
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}


\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

I want to achieve

[image]

**Now I get for**

> Even page

[image]

> Odd page

[image]

Comment: Page 241 (table 6.3) of this [manual](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) explains the options for `scrlayer-scrpage` which has similar functions an is newer than `scrpage2`. Still, the options for `scrpage2` may be found in that document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with fancyhr package

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}

\usepackage{calc} 

% Page layout
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt
%,bindingoffset=30pt
%,asymmetric
,reversemarginpar
,showframe]{geometry}


% Head and foot of all pages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\mainmatter
%% headings
\pagestyle{fancy}
%% General setup
%\fancyheadoffset[LO,RE]{-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth}
\fancyheadoffset[LO]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\fancyheadoffset[LE]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
%% Head
%\fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily\rightmark}
%\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\sffamily\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
%
%% Rules
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%% end headings
%\reversemarginpar

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

> Odd page
>   [image]
>
> Even page
>   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Edit: OP changed his question, so this answer is out of date. I don't delete it, because the code may serve as a starting point.

---

I have to confess, I did not quite understand your design, but this code seems to come quite close:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside=semi]{scrbook}

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt
%,bindingoffset=30pt
,asymmetric
,reversemarginpar
,showframe]{geometry}


\usepackage[ilines, headsepline, headwidth=340pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}


\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

You need a recent version of KOMA-script (v 3.12).

Comment: Wouldn't a symbolic `textwithmarginpar` be better? Quoting the documentation: “the width of the text body including margin”.

Comment: No it is not giving what i want...