# Changing the location of an element in the header using scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: fancyhdr, scrbook, scrlayer-scrpage

In fancyhr

```
\fancyheadoffset[LO]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
```

moves odd page left element in the header.

*Do we have any facility like this in **scrlayer-scrpage**?*

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside=semi]{scrbook}

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt
%,bindingoffset=30pt
,asymmetric
,reversemarginpar
,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}

\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you still interested? I'm asking, because you solved your other question http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170360/4736 by using fancyhr. And if yes, please give an MWE.

Comment: @keks-dose Yes, fancyhr is not recommended for KOMA script. I need to have scrlayer-scrpage solution. MWE added.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

The [KOMA-Script version 3.14](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) is already on CTAN. So you can use the new possibility of the `scrlayer-scrpage` option

```
headwidth=<headwidth>:<offset odd pages>:<offset even pages>
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside=semi]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  automark,
  headsepline,
  headwidth=textwithmarginpar:-\the\marginparwidth-\the\marginparsep:marginpar
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

You can try/test [the beta version (not stable) of koma-script](http://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/). In rev. 1757 Markus Kohm added the support of different offsets for odd and even pages. Then you can use

```
\usepackage[
  headsepline,
  headwidth=textwithmarginpar:-\the\marginparwidth-\the\marginparsep:marginpar
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

Comment: Will you attend to the 25. anniversary of DANTE this weekend in Heidelberg? Or to one of the next "Stammtisch" in Karlsruhe of TeXies?

Comment: @Keks Dose Yes, I will be in Heidelberg.